# Drools - ClassCastException while using RuleNameEndsWithAgendaFilter

Tags: drools

Here is the snippet of code that I'm using :

```
AgendaFilter filter = (AgendaFilter) new RuleNameEndsWithAgendaFilter("Test");
// Gives a compile time error if I don't cast it.
// Run the rules
int numOfRulesFired = stateFulKnowledgeSession.fireAllRules(filter);
```

This spits out a runtime Exception :

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.drools.base.RuleNameEndsWithAgendaFilter cannot be cast to org.drools.runtime.rule.AgendaFilter
```

Please let me know If I'm missing out something here.

Thanks,
Ashwin

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have the wrong `AgendaFilter`. I checked the latest Drools codes and `org.drools.runtime.rule.AgendaFilter` no longer exists or it is renamed to something better.

Use `org.drools.spi.AgendaFilter` and it works.